# jquery selector for radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am developing a php based programme for online test. There will be 25 random questions and the candidate has to answer 20 compulsory questions. In order to show whether the candidate has answered a question, I want to include Radio Click event so that when an option is clicked, the Serial Number of that question will get highlighted. I am able to check and uncheck the option button by the following jquery function:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').mousedown(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).mouseup(function(e) {
                var radio = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    radio.checked = false; 
                }, 5);

                $(this).unbind('mouseup');       
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am able to change the font size of the question number through the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if (this.checked==true){
            $("#tt_1").css("font-size", "25px");
        }
    });
});
```

However, I am not able to include ELSE condition in the above function so that the formatting is restored when the option button is deselected.

Please help me with the correct code.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier using `addClass('your-class')`, then defining the class in your CSS, than trying to restore/remove the CSS values through jQuery.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
    radios.click(function () {
        radios.each(function () {
            if (this.checked==true){
                $("#tt_1").addClass('bigger-font');
            }
            else $("#tt_1").removeClass('bigger-font');
        });

    });
});


<style>
.bigger-font {
    font-size: 25px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add an onblur event

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Or you could reset all the fields on click. e.g.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
  // Reset the state
});
```

Comment: I think it isn't a good idea to add the event 'onBlur', it will always fired when the radio field lose the focus.